# How to autosave notebooks in Google colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, autosave

I was recently working in a notebook on Google Colab and my computer ran out of battery and died. All the progress I had made was not saved anywhere! 
I'm very used to having jupyter notebooks, which saves my files pretty much every time I execute a cell.
Is there a way to have an equivalent feature in Google Colab?

Comment: This would be V useful

Answer (score 2):

**Autosave every 60 seconds** by running this "**magic command**" into a new code cell :

`%autosave 60`

Colab will confirm it when you run the cell with printing : "*Autosave changes every 60 seconds*"

To display the **list of all magic commands** you can use the command :

`%lsmagic`

Additionally, you can call the **Quick Reference Guide**, describing all the magic commands and what they do using the command :

`%quickref`

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Autosave is already implemented in Google Colab, but there is a certain delay between the moment you execute a cell and when the save occurs.

You can try this yourself by going into File>Revision History, executing a cell, and waiting for the list to refresh.

That being said, I have also experienced loss of data in the past, which I can't explain. It might be a glitch.

As a good practice, I try to save every time I remember.

Good luck.